# Why is RegOpenKeyEx() returning error code 2 on Vista 64bit?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-vista, registry, wow64

I was making the following call:

```
result = RegOpenKeyEx(key, s, 0, KEY_READ, &key);
```

(C++, Visual Studio 5, Vista 64bit).

It is failing with error code 2 ("File not found") even though "`regedit`" shows that the key exists.  This code has always worked on 32bit XP.  Why is it "file not found" when it clearly is there?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I discovered that I could solve my problem using the flag:   `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`  , as in:

```
result = RegOpenKeyEx(key, s, 0, KEY_READ|KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &key);
```

For a full explanation: [32-bit and 64-bit Application Data in the Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724072(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 26):

On a Windows 64-bit system the Registry is actually divided into two parts. One section is used by 64-bit processes, and one part by 32-bit processes.

For example, if a 32-bit application programatically writes to what it believes is HKLM\SOFTWARE\Company\Application, it's actually redirected by the WoW64-layer to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Company\Application.

So when you run your 32-bit application and call RegOpenKeyEx it's actually working against the Wow6432Node\ folder, and not the regular \SOFTWARE node.

Comment: Note that you should not rely on the key being called "Wow6432Node". Access the other registry view using the flags to `RegOpenKeyEx` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile with "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" or cast string in code to (LPWSTR)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
I was using:

```
dwResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                                   (LPWSTR)"SOFTWARE\\0test",
                                   0,
                                   WRITE_DAC ,
                                   &hKey);
```

That didn't work.  I tried it like this and it worked:

```
dwResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                                   _T("SOFTWARE\\0test"),
                                   0,
                                   WRITE_DAC ,
                                   &hKey);
```

Comment: Never just insert casts to shut up the compiler. The compiler correctly refused to compile the first one without a cast.

Answer (score 0):

yes，win7 64B,add further flag KEY_WOW64_64KEY ,it will work.
if not work, refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724897(v=VS.85).aspx