# Unable to see certain HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE entries in RegEdit

Tags: delphi, registry

I'm using HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to set a variable at the time of install. These need to be seen by all users on a machine and are only read by them.

I use Inno to create the entry. It's running as admin, so it should have adequate rights that virtualization doesn't kick in ... or am I misunderstanding?

My application can read the entry (even as a limited user in Win7) BUT I can't see them in RegEdit or RegEditX 3.0.  I CAN see them in RegEditX 2.0 though. Weird.

I don't understand why my Delphi app can see the entry, but the RegEdit programs above can't.

I believe that this might have something to so with virtualization (first answer here: [Cannot read config data from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE on Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691433/cannot-read-config-data-from-hkey-local-machine-on-vista)).

But, I can't even see the registry entry in question under HKCU\Software\Classes\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE.

Is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE so deprecated that I should be avoiding it completely?  How is a developer now supposed to save data for all users - just in {commomappdata}, which usually is C:\Program Data... ??

Comment: You might want to look into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` if you're on 64-bit.

Comment: @Polynomial Surely that's the answer. Why don't you post it as such?

Comment: Wasn't entirely sure, but looks like the case. I'll post as an answer.

Comment: @polynomial I'm 99.9% certain this will be it. I bet that RegeditX is a 32 bit process from the old days.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Most likely. The interesting thing is that explicit operations on `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` in 32-bit processes seems to work for me...

Comment: @Polynomial That makes no sense. Perhaps there is code in the redirector to protect you from yourself!!!

Comment: I am reminded of Xzibit: *"Yo dawg, I herd u like redirects, so we put redirects in yo redirects so you can redirect while you redirect"*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

64-bit versions of Windows emulate 32-bit functionality through the "Windows on Windows" (WoW) subsystem. In the case of the registry, they move the 32-bit keys over to a special subkey for compatibility reasons.

The keys will be in: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`.

This is the registry analogue of the file system redirector that maps `system32` to `SysWOW64`.

More details can be found on the MSDN topic about the [Registry Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I thought I was going mad not being able to find some records in the registry that I knew were hiding in there!